# как узнать какие есть id для canberra?

Tags: linux, gtk

сделал программу и там использую canberra. но я знаю только два id. и в документации не могу найти информацию о всех доступных id. где же их искать? у меня ubuntu.

Comment: конкретезируйте проблему и добавьте примеры

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://0pointer.de/public/sound-naming-spec.html

Стандартные звуки обозначенны в спецификации

Comment: Вау. спасибо большое.